# How to find number of hits for webpage in Splunk?

Tags: count, html, splunk

I've tried things like:

1. "url" | stats count
2. index="indexname" "url" |stats count

Do I need to set up logging in my webpage first to be able to get the number of hits?

Comment: I thing we are going to need more information. What are you trying to do ? What do you mean by "number of hits for webpage" ?

Comment: Meaning the number of people that visit a page

Comment: Yes, but what kind of data do you have ? Access logs ? Can you show a sample ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splunk App called "Website input"

App Link: https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1818/

You can get much more statistics for your webpage than just number of hits.